# How can I pass a jsx react component (with prop) into a Navbar component with a Dropdown properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am trying to pass a list (NavItemsList) into my navbar so that it populates the "right-nav-container" div with the list items and their respective sub navigations with a drop down component. I am new to React.Js so correct me if I am wrong; In the right side of the container, I am reading a list with a certain index and mapping its values. I have my code set up so that once it maps the values, it will return my "NavItems" component with the "items" prop that I created. Inside the NavItems component, I have a conditional statement that is meant to check if the list that is read has a sub navigation section in the index. If it has a sub navigation then the Dropdown component I made is passed which also has another prop named submenus, otherwise just the index title is passed into the the navbar. Inside the dropdown component, I have passed "submenus" as a prop (I think) which is used to get the subNav values for the dropdown. My problem is that when I pass the NavItems component inside the Navbar file, my entire Navbar disappears but when I comment out `return <NavItems items={menu} key={index} />;` my Navbar loads as normal (without links in the right container). This leads me to believe I am doing something in wrong in one of the following components.

Navbar.jsx section:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './Navbar.css';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';
import {NavItemsList} from './NavItemsList';
import NavItems from './NavItems';

function Navbar() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false); 
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);
    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click); //Since the state is initially false (set above), clicking it will set the state to the opposite because of the ! sign.
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

    const onMouseEnter = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setDropdown(false);
        } else {
            setDropdown(true);
        }
    };

    const onMouseLeave = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setDropdown(false);
        } else {
            setDropdown(false);
        }
    };

    return (
<div className='right-nav-container'>
                        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                            <div className='text-links'>
                                {NavItemsList.slice(0, 4).map((menu, index) => {
                                    return <NavItems items={menu} key={index} />;
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <div className='logo-links'>
                                {NavItemsList.slice(4, 6).map((menu, index) => {
                                    return <NavItems items={menu} key={index} />;
                                })}
                            </div>
                );
}

export default Navbar;
```

NavItems.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function NavItems(items) {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

    return (
        <li className='nav-item'>
            {items.subNav ? (
                <>
                    <Link
                        className={items.cName}
                        to={items.path}
                        onClick={() => setClick(false)}
                    >
                        {items.title}
                    </Link>
                    <Dropdown submenus={items.subNav} />
                </>
            ) : (
                <Link
                    className={items.cName}
                    to={items.path}
                    onClick={() => setClick(false)}
                >
                    {items.title}
                </Link>
            )}
        </li>
    );
}

export default NavItems;
```

Dropdown.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
function Dropdown(submenus) {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

    return (
        <ul
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}
        >
            {submenus.map((subNav, index) => (
                <li key={index} className='dropdown-links'>
                    <Link
                        className={subNav.cName}
                        to={subNav.path}
                        onClick={() => setClick(false)}
                    >
                        {subNav.title}
                    </Link>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

NavItemsList.js object example:

```
{
        title: 'Create',
        path: '/create',
        cName: 'nav-links',
        subNav: [
            {
                title: 'Pixel Art',
                path: '/create/pixelart',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
            },
            {
                title: 'Upload',
                path: '/create/upload',
                cName: 'dropdown-link',
            },
        ],
    },
```

Any help would be appreciated so much. I have been trying to solve this but just keep getting a blank screen when I load the react app.

Here is a code sandbox with the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sound-ljc073?file=/src/NavItemsList.js

Comment: I'm having a difficult time seeing how the issues you describe could occur without any errors being produced. Are you any errors in the console? Think you could create a running codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Somehow I am not getting any errors in the console, it’s just not displaying anything I had previously when I add the  NavItems component. But yes, I will definitely be posting a demo ASAP. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Here is a live demo of the issue. Thank you to anyone that can help! https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sound-ljc073?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: I figured out that my Vs code is not configured to display the errors that are actually in the code. I will continue to work on this and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `NavItems` and `Dropdown` components are syntactically correct but you've named the `props` object something else in each, `items` and `submenus` respectively. Each component then references the *entire* "props" object as if it were the *specific* `items` or `submenus` prop that was passed.

## Solution

Either rename each to `props` and access accordingly:

```
function NavItems(props) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

  return (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <Link
        className={props.items.cName}
        to={props.items.path}
        onClick={() => setClick(false)}
      >
        {props.items.title}
      </Link>
      {props.items.subNav && <Dropdown submenus={props.items.subNav} />}
    </li>
  );
}
```

...

```
function Dropdown(props) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

  return (
    <ul
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={click ? "dropdown-menu clicked" : "dropdown-menu"}
    >
      {props.submenus.map((subNav, index) => (
        <li key={index} className="dropdown-links">
          <Link
            className={subNav.cName}
            to={subNav.path}
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
          >
            {subNav.title}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Or destructure the passed props:

```
function NavItems({ items }) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

  return (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <Link
        className={items.cName}
        to={items.path}
        onClick={() => setClick(false)}
      >
        {items.title}
      </Link>
      {items.subNav && <Dropdown submenus={items.subNav} />}
    </li>
  );
}
```

...

```
function Dropdown({ submenus }) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);

  return (
    <ul
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={click ? "dropdown-menu clicked" : "dropdown-menu"}
    >
      {submenus.map((subNav, index) => (
        <li key={index} className="dropdown-links">
          <Link
            className={subNav.cName}
            to={subNav.path}
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
          >
            {subNav.title}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-pass-a-jsx-react-component-with-prop-into-a-navbar-component-with-a]